# Why use isolated storage in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to store user preferences on a per page basis in my application.  For example, several pages use a custom grid pager control that needs to keep its current page size between postbacks.  Most of the settings don't need to persist once the user leaves the page, but in some situations they do need to be restored.  **Note: Session is disabled in this application and will not be used.**

I did some reading on isolated storage and understand that it can be used to store these user settings.  Obviously cookies have been around a long time and are a proven approach to this scenario, but what about isolated storage?  Is it going to work for all browsers and in all environments?  Are permissions a problem?  Does it require configuring anything on the end-user's side?  Just how widely used is it?  Why should one use isolated storage in an application for the given example?

Thanks!

Comment: If the settings are simple and only need to be persisted between postbacks, consider using ViewState.

Comment: I can on the pages that have viewstate enabled, but not all of them have viewstate enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously cookies have been around a
>   long time and are a proven approach to
>   this scenario, but what about isolated
>   storage? Is it going to work for all
>   browsers and in all environments?

Ah - .NET isolated storage is SERVER SIDE. Like a database. It is meant as a small way to store small amounts of data( ONE user, not all users, viewstate) on the side the .NET application runs (in asp.net case = the server).

As such it is totally irrelvant to your question.

Put the data in a database. I know of VERY few usages of isolated stoage for ASP.NET applications, it craetes a TON of long term problems. It is not meant for server side apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use hidden form field variables on a per-page basis, as a way to keep track of that page's state.

This is my preference to a session state strategy to deal with the scenario of users having say 2 FireFox browser instances open to the same page. No need to deal with session state issues in that scenario.