# How do I persist a user's profile in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I am a newbie to ASP.NET - so what is the pattern to use Isolated Storage vs. Session state for web applications?

I have a use case where when a user logs into the application, I need to create his profile information which will persist throughout his session.

Does it make sense to store this in session or should I use Isolated Storage (assuming the client is on a Windows machine)

Thanks!

Comment: If you use and ORM technology for persistence, like NHibernate of Entity Framework. Use a forms authentication ticket (cookie) to store the user id at the client. At the Authenticate_Request event, load the User entity corresponding to the logged user based on the cookie and store it in a request context, like HttpContext.Current.Items

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a [profile provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.aspx) that's built to store a user's profile.

You could use your own provider that's session backed if you really only want the profile to last for the duration of the session.

Your last comment makes me think you want to use isolated storage on the client machine; I don't think you can access isolated storage on the client from a browser w/o an ActiveX control or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated storage is not used in asp.net applications for storing profile info - this is generally used in .net apps running on the client side.

To get profiles up and running, see any of the many posting on it.. a good one by Dino Esposito 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx

The configuration is there by default but in visual studio you will want to bring up the admin site for your web app to make sure everything is setup.

Using web applications or web sites also gives you different access to profile properties. One will strongly type them, one will not.

Comment: The poster has a misunderstanding of isolated storage, and I think you do too.  Isolated storage IS and CAN BE used in asp.net applications.  When used this way, though, it is the store of the server, and not that of the client machine (unless it is used inside of a Silverlight application).

Comment: @Gabriel I think you misunderstood the context. I completely understand isolated storage, along with the lack of any real security on it, backup issues, etc. Based on the original post for profile,asp.net is not an environment for it and it really isn't used in any decently architected asp.net application. Obviously you 'can' as its part of the framework, and therefore available to most environments that use the framework. However - for profiles it is not recommended and should not be used. Before saying it "IS" used in asp.net for a new user, please read the many postings as to why you

Comment: shouldn't. My post was specific to standard profile usage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726954/why-use-isolated-storage-in-an-asp-net-application

Comment: I agree.  It shouldn't be used for user profiles.  My comment was only that that was not what you said.  You asked that I be specific (for new users), but you weren't as specific as you could have been.  Your answer said that isolated storage is not used in asp.net applications.  That is not true.  I have seen many cases where it is used as a temporary storage location while processing uploaded files.  Just be specific in your answers.  It will help more people if you do.

Comment: It is not meant to be used for profile info. I'll edit and add those three words. The rest of the post is spot on... Guess it deserved a downvote